# Add missing case statement with break

Tags: eclipse, editor, switch-statement

I'm trying to find out how to have my eclipse automatically add a `break;` line when I use the Add missing case statements shortcut. Right now it only adds each enum stacked one after the other, so I have to add them manually. I looked for this question also...

I'm using Indigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone has this problem, If you have a `default:` set when you do "add missing case statements" in a switch, eclipse won't break the statements it adds.

When I asked this question the `default:` was being added automatically by eclipse, so I thought it was a setting I missed.